# Equivalence class over a set of natural numbers with conditions

Tags: equivalence-relations

My discrete math class has this problem: we need to find the equivalence classes for the equivalence relation over the set of $\mathcal{N}$ onto $\mathcal{N}$ defined as follows:
$$xRy \iff (x-3.3)(y-3.6)>0$$
I thought that there's only 1 class: $\{\mathcal{N}-{0,1,2,3}\}$ that is all natural numbers greater than 3. However the solution says that there's another equivalance class: $\{0,1,2,3\}$. But how can this be? 
$$1R2 \to (1-3.3)(2-3,6) <0$$
so clearly such input renders the output to be below zero hence it can't be part of the relation.

Comment: How is it less than zero? Both terms are negative, so the product $(1-3.3)(2-3.6)$ is greater than zero.  For greater clarification,  that product is $3.68$. This is an equivalence relation because there is no natural number between $3.3$ and $3.6$.

Comment: you're right I was confused with the product. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Top mathematicians make this mistake, so nobody's new to it.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-3.3)(2-3.6)\color{red}{>}0$$
or more generally
$$x\cdot y>0\iff (x>0\ \land  y>0)\ \lor \ (x<0\ \land  y<0)$$